# Declaring object's key type in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

first time using Typescript, I'm a bit confused about how I should do this. I have and object with these keys:

```
interface eachUserInt {
    avatar: string;
    name: string;
    uid: string;
    friends: userInterface[];
    requests: userInterface[];
  }
```

The userInterface is this:

```
interface userInterface {
    name: string;
    avatar: string;
    uid: string;
  }
```

So the `requests` key is an object with keys name, avatar and uid, right?
I'm declaring the state as:

```
const [eachUser, setEachUser] = useState<eachUserInt | null>(null);
```

Below all of it, i have this:

```
const friend: userInterface = eachUser?.requests[index];
```

But it throws the error:

```
Type 'userInterface | undefined' is not assignable to type 'userInterface'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'userInterface'
```

What am i missing here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give `friend` a fallback value if `eachUser?.requests[index]` evaluates to null.

Answer (score 0):

Its just as the error says

Since `friend` is of type `userInterface` and `eachUser?.requests[index];` can return either `undefined` or `userInterface` it would cause that error. To fix this, you just tell typescript it could also be undefined.

```
const friend: userInterface | undefined = eachUser?.requests[index];
```

Comment: I tried that, and then when i wrote friend.name it says that it's possibly undefined. So this time i tried friend?.name and it worked! Thank you! 
But am i doing it correctly? I mean, i feel like i'm not following best practices hahaha

Comment: Yes. As you can see, if you ddn't write `undefined`, then `friend.name` in regular javascript could error because `undefined` doesn't have property name. So `friend?.name` would be the appropiate action

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgogFgVQM7QJLjIDeAUMucnAG5xhxQBcy2YUoA5gNxkUhwC2EJizYguPcgFdgAE2GsO3CshhsIIGdiaTcUApFiIIAbQC6SilAgBHSRBbYA-Nt37o8JGYsBfEgHo-ABV0FB18cHcjZGBsZDB0GIYSElADD1DXCMMkYglkPkF5UXFlalp6IsU86TlmBTEffz8AZQB7OJDkK1t7MFiAawgAT2jYuBBkVoAjACsIBDBkAHdgeORBodiCiAAaSho6KEoNZBq9tnZ0MEdkPAByfmQZeYAbeg4OlBZaFDgtZIQrRALFQGBw0AYaAQWEyiwAvEQyocGHcAEx3HbbFEARlRuIxqmA6k0DDMOxqOLuvgCACEIC9WktKC8XpMYNEwHtgMh0NQUPFEgCgSDQM8AB7IOHIAAMJEBwMWhOJLnCaSMAB9JBoIDBQBAZJLQdDwVBHAA6bp2Bzm4yiiBi8wkIA)
Firstly your `requests` property is not nullable (`?.`) currently.
So it needs to be;

`requests?: userInterface[];`

Secondly, if it's nullable you'll need to do a null coalesce:

`eachUser?.requests?.[index];`

Otherwise you'd get a `Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)` error.